# Need some support writing a MySQL-Query

Tags: mysql, database, select, relational

I'm writing a basic message-script in PHP/MySQL but I'm stuck at a database query right now. I'll appreciate any hints or assistance (:

I'm using two tables, since a message can be sent to several users:

```
messages:
id | sender_id | subject | ...

message_receivers:
message_id | receiver_id | ...
```

What I want to do now is display a message to the user that he selects. But I want to show the whole message history the user had in that conversation (jumping in browser to the one he selected). Doing this with a join is quite simple:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
    JOIN message_receivers 
    ON messages.id = message_receivers.message_id
    WHERE sender_id = x
    AND receiver_id = y
```

But now I'm missing the information of other receivers of a message! And I have no clue how to get this information. Any ideas for that? (:

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "missing the information of other receivers of a message".  Are you looking for one query that will return a conversation between two users?  It's hard to see what you need exactly.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a query to get the whole conversation between two users (and the JOIN-Statement above is already doing this). But the result of the query won't tell me if a message in that conversation had other receivers too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `message_receivers` table one more time to retrieve the other recipients of the message:

```
SELECT
    m.id, m.sender_id, m.subject,
    r.receiver_id AS recipient,
    c.receiver_id AS carboncopy
FROM messages AS m
INNER JOIN message_receivers AS r
    ON m.id = r.message_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN message_receivers AS c
    ON r.message_id = c.message_id AND r.receiver_id != c.receiver_id
WHERE m.sender_id = x AND r.receiver_id = y
```

The recipient that your are interested in will be in column `recipient` (in every result record). Other recipients will be in column `carboncopy` (one per result record). If `carboncopy` is `NULL`, then the message had only a single receiver.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the query and its description! Exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all the receivers of a message then remove the second part of the were clause:

```
AND receiver_id = y
```

at the same time you will want to specify the message_id because this will be to confusing to the user on the front end

```
AND message_id = z
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing information about other receivers of the message because of the clasue:

```
AND
receiver_id = y
```

This restricts the result set to just receiver `y`. Remove the clause, and you'll get them all. However you'll probably get every message sent where `sender_id = x` as well, so you'll need to limit the query by specifying a `message_id`.

So your final query should look something like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
messages
JOIN message_receivers ON messages.id = message_receivers.message_id
WHERE
sender_id = x
AND
message_id = y
```

Comment: If I specify a certain message_id in the where clause I won't catch the whole conversation ):

Comment: @d.hill Ah, I didn't realise that the conversation could be built up of multiple messages. You might be better off using two queries here, seeing as you're trying to find two sets of information. Try using one query to get the conversation, and another to get the receivers.

Comment: Yes, but could I write this into one query with multiple selects? I'm rather unexperienced in that. Writing a query for each message to check if there are other receivers would be easy but way too much.

Comment: @d.hill How do you tell if two messages are in the same conversation?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to restrict your result to receiver_id = y, do you?
Also you might write the statement in a different way and easily return receivers ids:

```
SELECT m.*, r.receiver_id
FROM messages m, message_receivers r
WHERE m.id = r.message_id
AND m.sender_id = x
```